# how can avoid overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I want to try to do on hover multiple icon show on image. when the mouse is hovering the image multiple font awesome  icon become show with different link.

But icon become overlapped.

how can  avoid?

Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="profile-img-container">
<img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/765-default-avatar.png" class="img-thumbnail img-circle img-responsive" />
    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-youtube"></span></a>
    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.profile-img-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; /* added */
    overflow: hidden; /* added */
        display: inline-block;
}

.profile-img-container img {width:100%;} /* remove if using in grid system */


.profile-img-container img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
        display: inline-block;
}
.profile-img-container:hover a {
    opacity: 1; /* added */
    top: 0; /* added */
    z-index: 500;
        display: inline-block;
}
/* added */
.profile-img-container:hover a span {
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
        display: inline-block;
}
/* added */
.profile-img-container a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: inherit;
         display: inline-block; /* added */
}
```

[**DEMO:Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/prtkqb44/360/)

Comment: Don't have time to give you a full answer, but by having the one selector for your icons and using that to absolutely position them they will overlap as you have given them the same co-ordinates. Solutions: don't use position absolute or position the elements individually.

Comment: i try randomly. now i become puzzled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap them in an element and center that element instead of the individual icons.

```css
.profile-img-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; /* added */
    overflow: hidden; /* added */
  display: inline-block;
}

.profile-img-container img {width:100%;} /* remove if using in grid system */


.profile-img-container img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
  display: inline-block;
}
.profile-img-container:hover .icons {
    opacity: 1; /* added */
    z-index: 500;
}
.icons {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  position: absolute;
}

/* added */
.profile-img-container a {
    color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="profile-img-container">
<img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/765-default-avatar.png" class="img-thumbnail img-circle img-responsive" />
  <div class="icons">
  <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-youtube fa-5x"></span></a>
    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook fa-5x"></span></a>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting the icons in a container and centering them with the right z-index will do the trick. see below.

```css
.profile-img-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /* added */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.profile-img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2
}


/* remove if using in grid system */

.profile-img-container img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: inline-block;
}

.profile-img-container:hover .icon-cont {
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon-cont {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transition: .4s;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="profile-img-container">
  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/765-default-avatar.png" class="img-thumbnail img-circle img-responsive" />
  <div class="icon-cont">
    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-youtube fa-5x"></span></a>
    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook fa-5x"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```